# Recycleviewer - How to reuse the layout?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-recyclerview

I'm using [this](https://github.com/mikepenz/FastAdapter) library to handle my `RecycleView` to add items. I have a layout with an `ImageView` and a class. I have a list of an object and I want to add those to the `RecycleView`.

So basically like this:

My `item_main.xml`:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/frame"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/cover_image"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="264dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

</FrameLayout>
```

My `activity_main.xml` (not all of it):

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:scrollbars="vertical"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

And my class `MyObject`:

```
public class MyObject extends AbstractItem<MyObject, MyObject.ViewHolder> implements Serializable  {
    @SerializedName(value="id")
    private int id;
    @SerializedName(value="name")
    private String name;
    @Expose
    private String linkToImage;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public int getType() {
        return R.id.image;
    }

    //The layout to be used for this type of item
    @Override
    public int getLayoutRes() {
        return R.layout.item_main;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(ViewHolder viewHolder, List<Object> payloads) {
        //call super so the selection is already handled for you
        super.bindView(viewHolder, payloads);

        //bind our data
        //set the text for the name
        Picasso.with(viewHolder.itemView.getContext())
                .load(linkToImage)
                .into(viewHolder.image);
    }

    //The viewHolder used for this item. This viewHolder is always reused by the RecyclerView so scrolling is blazing fast
    protected static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        protected ImageView image;
        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            this.image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.cover_image);
        }
    }
}
```

That works very well. The thing is now that I would like to reuse this in another `Activity` with a different `RecycleView` but the same `List<MyObject>` and the same `item_main.xml`.

I tried to use the same code I have in `MainActivity`. It seems to add the items (it prints out the name in the `onClick`) but it does not load the images.

Here's my code in the `MainActivity`:

```
RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.mainRecycleView);
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), 2));

FastItemAdapter fastAdapter = new FastItemAdapter();

mRecyclerView.setAdapter(fastAdapter);
fastAdapter.add(listOfMyObjects);
DefaultItemAnimator animator = new DefaultItemAnimator() {
    @Override
    public boolean canReuseUpdatedViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
        return true;
    }
};
fastAdapter.withSelectable(true);
fastAdapter.withOnClickListener(new FastAdapter.OnClickListener<MyObject>() {
    @Override
    public boolean onClick(View v, IAdapter<MyObject> adapter, MyObjectitem, int position) {
        Log.d("DEBUG", item.getName());
        return true;
    }
});
mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(animator);
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Does it throw any error in logcat?

Comment: @ReazMurshed - nope, it starts the activity normally, loads the data (The List<MyObject>) and even loads it into the RecycleView, it just doesnt display the image

Comment: Please see the answer below. There's a potential bug here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a potential bug in your `ViewHolder` though I really don't know how it works in `MainActivity`.

You've set `item_main.xml` in your `getLayoutRes` function and in your `ViewHolder` you're getting the `ImageView` reference from wrong layout id.

So your `ViewHolder` should look like this.

```
protected static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    protected ImageView image;
    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);

        // Set the proper layout id cover_image here
        this.image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.cover_image);
    }
}
```

**Update**

As you've mistakenly put the wrong layout id in the question, so I think the bug is not there. But anyway, I have found other problems here that you might need to check.

In your `MainActivity` you're setting the adapter first and then you're adding objects in your adapter. So you might do this

```
// Add the items first
fastAdapter.add(listOfMyObjects);

// Then set the adapter
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(fastAdapter);
```

Or you can do this in your way

```
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(fastAdapter);
fastAdapter.add(listOfMyObjects);

// Notify the adapter that new elements have added
fastAdapter.notifyDatasetChanged();
```

And please check if the image links are valid.

Personally, I use Glide for loading images. You might have a look at Glide for image loading too.

```
Glide.with(viewHolder.itemView.getContext())
    .load(linkToImage)
    .into(viewHolder.image);
```

Comment: My bad, I edited out some names/ids to make it simpler and seemed to forget to change the image to the R.id.cover_image. In my code it has always been like you have it. Thanks a lot though!

Comment: Okay. Edited the question accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Sadly it did not work and I noticed that the problem is not with adding the items but with loading the image.

Comment: Are the link to the images valid? And, personally I prefer Glide for loading images.

Comment: I'm very sorry for wasting your time :( I just forgot to set the link to the images properly as in this activity they are not set but in my main they are. Thank you very much for the help :)